# Is there a bug in Google Directions API?

Tags: android, google-maps, directions

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=12.8858475,77.5908135&destination=13.2044921,77.7076907&alternatives=true&key=xxxxx&departure_time=now

The above is a sample request (Based in Bangalore). The API usually returns 3 routes, but there seems to be only 2 distinct routes.

Am i wrongly reading the output or is there a bug here? If there is a bug how do I get it rectified

Answer (score 0):

The API is correct and there is no bug. There are indeed 3 routes. Using the URL that you provided, I used a [JSON Editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to interpret the data and it shows 3 objects inside routes array. 
Instead of reading the JSON data manually, try the editor. You can also try to read more about JSON parsing in this [Gogle Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#ParsingJSON). Google provided a snippet that might be of use.

> ```
> for (i = 0; i < myJSONResult.results.length; i++) {
>      myAddress[i] = myJSONResult.results[i].formatted_address;
> }
> ```

Comment: please read the question carefully - 3 routes are returned but only 2 of them are distinct, 1 seems to be a duplicate